# Check if an array of objects have a key value using underscore

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js

How can check if an array of objects have a key value using underscore.

Example:

```
var objects = [
  {id:1, name:'foo'},
  {id:2, name:'bar'}
]

check(objects, {name: foo}) // true
```

I think it should be made using map:

```
_.map(objects, function(num, key){ console.log(num.name) });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find` http://underscorejs.org/#find

```
var check = function (thelist, props) {
    var pnames = _.keys(props);
    return _.find(thelist, function (obj) {
        return _.all(pnames, function (pname) {
            return obj[pname] == props[pname];
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 49):

You can use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for this.

```
check = objects.some( function( el ) {
    return el.name === 'foo';
} );
```

`check` is `true` if the function returned `true` once, otherwise it's `false`.

Not supported in IE7/8 however. You can see the MDN link for a shim.

For the underscore library, it looks like it's implemented too (it's an alias of [`any`](http://underscorejs.org/#any)). Example:

```
check = _.some( objects, function( el ) {
    return el.name === 'foo';
} );
```

Comment: How about checking that there is one such object in the array?